# Network Manager icon doesn't appear in top panel

Tags: 11.10, network-manager

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I have a problem with *network-manager* because the icon in top bar disappeared and I don't know how to get it back.

I tried to edit *NetworkManager.conf* and set *true* in *managed* but nothing happened.

How do I get the network manager icon in the top panel back?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Unity, try to log off and choose *Ubuntu Classic*.

After that, see if the network manager is on the top bar. If it's not, then you can do this :

- Right click on the top Bar, and choose *Add to Panel*
- Just double click on *Indicator Applet* or *Indicator Applet Complete*